# FactoyGirl: before(:create) actions not being recognized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot, has-many, belongs-to

I am attempting to create my FactoryGirl factories such that when I call `FactoryGirl.create(:model_a)`, any **dependency** for **model_a** are created and assigned to that model_a factory. However, for some reason my method is not working and I can't quite figure out why.

In my factory file this is what I have:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :model_a do
        before(:create) do
            FactoryGirl.create(:model_b)
        end

        model_b {ModelB.first}
    end
end
```

Now when I run `FactoryGirl.create(:model_a)` I would expect this to first create the factory **model_b** (because of the *before(:create)* call) and then go back to creating the factory **model_a** and assigning the factory **model_b** to the **model_b** relationshionship for **model_a**

But instead, I am getting the error `model_b must exist, model_b cannot be blank`.

Why is the factory model_b not being created so that I can use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the association between `model_a` and `model_b` inside your `before(:create)` block. For example:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :model_a do
    # add model_a attributes as needed

    before(:create) do |model_a|
      model_a.model_b = ModelB.first || FactoryGirl.create(:model_b)
    end
  end
end
```

Or, per OP's comment:

```
factory :model_a do
  # add model_a attributes as needed
  model_b { ModelB.first || FactoryGirl.create(:model_b) }
end
```

Comment: Okay, now is there any difference in doing that and doing `FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :model_a do
    # add model_a attributes as needed

      model_b = ModelB.first || FactoryGirl.create(:model_b)
  end
end`

Comment: sorry, I can't seem to figure out how to do a newline in comments, it just ends up posting the comment... But is there any difference in doing that and just setting the **model_b** attribute the same way outside of the before(:create) function? like so: `model_b { ModelB.first || FactoryGirl.create(:model_b) }`

Comment: Okay sweet! I found out that the `model_b { ModelB.first || FactoryGirl.create(:model_b) }` method is best for when testing models This is because if you are trying to manipulate attributes for your tests by using `@instance = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:model_a)` and then manipulating **@instance** attributes before attempting to save, the actions inside of *before(:create)* will never activate, whereas the other method they will. Thanks!